# optimized query with spring jpa data hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring JPA data in my data access object layer. I have an entity "Project" that make reference to another entity "Stage" with an association one To Many. I have the projectId and the new stage will be added to the collection of stages. I can retrieve the project and create the new stage then I add the stage to the collection and finally persist the project object But I want to know a solution more optimized as the mine make many connections to the database.

Comment: If you have your transactions setup correctly there is only a single connection to the database. You might have a couple of round trips but is that really a problem...

Comment: Would you explain to me with a simple  example ? you mean that I should add the @transactional annotation over every method in my repository class ?

Comment: What you describe should happen in a service method and that service method should be transactional. During the transaction there is only a single physical connection with the database.